# what is equivalent of 'tab' from eclipse in intellij idea IDE

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, intellij-idea

Is there any equivalent of <kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> from eclipse.
For example if I am calling a method in eclipse it goes like,

```
method(10) //eclipse auto completes method and after writing 10 I can press tab to go to end to put ;
```

I can press <kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> to go to end, and put semi colon.

In Android-Studio(intellij idea) I have to manually go to end to put ;

Is there any way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Thanks so much Angelos

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + Shift + Enter should help.